# What is the difference between 'The carpet lies on the floor.' and 'The carpet is lying on the floor.'?

Tags: grammar, present-continuous

There are two sentences,

> 1. The carpet lies on the floor.
> 2. The carpet is lying on the floor.

What is the difference between the two sentences?
And under what situation should we use 'present progressive' with a stative verb?

Comment: Carpets do not lie on floors. Also, wall-to-wall carpet and a carpet are different. Wall-to-wall carpet or carpeting is put in or lain (installed) in a room. Carpets are on the floor. (like an area rug). People can lie on the floor  or a mat to do exercises. A dog can lie on the floor or on a sofa. Cats often lie around on furniture (if they are allowed to). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you won't go wrong if you use simple present with general truths:

> A carpet covers a floor.

and use the progressive with particular situations:

> She couldn't see if there was hardwood beneath it because the carpet
>   was completely covering the floor.

Here, the progressive/continuous contributes to the idea that the floor covering was *uninterrupted*, that is, there were no sections of bare floor.