# Could the pronoun be existing in the former section of the sentence?

Tags: grammar

**[SOURCE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/137630/37009)**

I saw the sentence in an answer to my previous question:

> "She couldn't see if there was hardwood beneath it because the carpet was completely covering the floor."

Could the pronoun be existing in the former section of the sentence?

I think that pronoun should be existing in the later section of the sentence like

> "She couldn't see if there was hardwood beneath the carpet because it was completely covering the floor."

Am I wrong?

Comment: It depends on the context to some degree. If we assume "it" refers to the carpet and the carpet has not been mentioned before, then yes, your revision is better.

Comment: In this case, yes, you are wrong. In your original question, the carpet was mentioned several times. This made the antecedent of _it_ quite clear in @Tᴚoɯɐuo's example sentence. You should consult your English language dictionary to understand what we mean when we use the word _context_.

Comment: Pronouns can be cataphoric or anaphoric.

Comment: *When I brought it in to be cleaned, this suit had a vest.*

Comment: Deciding between cataphora and anaphora is a question of information packaging. Both are grammatical.

Comment: When I took it to the mechanic for the annual state vehicle inspection, my car did not pass because it needed new brakes.